# approach to build the functionality to add new employee

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am newbie to intuit Platform APIs.

I started playing with the sample application and I am able to get the customer from the quickbooks online using REST apis.

My goal is : to create new employee with details for any customer using REST apis.

if anyone can just give me rough idea of how to go about it that will be helpful.

Comment: No one here will do research for you. Stackoverflow is geared towards answering problems with code, not writing code. Best of luck

Comment: I am not asking to write a program. I am just looking for approach. If you can point me to any specific github repo OR any examples that woule be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create new employee object using QB REST APIs( It is not supported in V2 and this entity is not release yet in V3)

**V2** https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/0500_supported_entities_and_operations

**V3** https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3/030_entity_services_reference/0500_v3_supported_entities_and_operations

Thanks